# Executable JAR - Is not using the test classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I have a project TestNG Selenium with the following structure:

```
src---
      |main
         |Annotations
         |Generate_Reports
         |....
      |testCases
         |Mobile
         |Web
         |....
resources ---
      |Drivers
      |GUI_Image
      |.....
```

I have also a GUI that add data based on testCases structure e.g. *src//testCases//* - will bring in the interface the available suite of testCases Mobile/Web etc.

When I create a executable JAR and I package the required libraries in the GUI the drop-downs are not populated with info and also the GUI_Images are not loaded.

What I can do? Looking into the jar the structure is different:

```
      |main
         |Annotations
         |Generate_Reports
         |....
      |testCases
         |Mobile
         |Web
         |....
```

Thanks,

Comment: As i see you re suing maven , please put your resources under src/main/resources

Comment: All build systems that I've seen, not just Maven, will ignore the `/test` directory when building release (Jar) files.  Normally you'd never want to see any test data in your final product.

Comment: I'm not using maven, it is an automation framework with UI. That will bring data in the drop-downs based on folder contents. E.g. user can select what suite of testcases want to execute mobile/web ... after that the Scenarios(classes) and TestCases methods are displayed.